# Linux - Sort file by date field

Tags: linux, file, date, converters

I am trying to sort a file by a date field. I realize this has been done before, however, I cannot find an example that has the following date format.

For example:
I have a file that contains:

```
example 1234 Sep/30/2013
example 1234 Jun/2014
example 1234 Oct/03/2013
example 1234 Oct/03/2013
example 1234 Oct/04/2013
example 1234 Oct/01/2013
```

How can I sort that by the date field?

Thanks in advanced!

Edit:
Here is my exact data (noticed I missed one field)

```
Bones + 9x03 + El Carnicero en el Coche + Sep/30/2013
Haven + 4x04 + Lost and Found + Oct/04/2013
Switched at Birth + 3x01 + Season 3, Episode 1 + Jan/2014
Sleepy Hollow + 1x03 + For the Triumph of Evil + Sep/30/2013
Greys Anatomy + 10x03 + Everybody's Crying Mercy + Oct/03/2013
Falling Skies + 4x01 + Season 4, Episode 1 + Jun/2014
New Girl + 3x03 + Double Date + Oct/01/2013
```

Here is the command I ran:
sort -t'+' -k 4 -M schedule | column -t -s'+'

```
Switched at Birth                 3x01     Season 3, Episode 1                  Jan/2014
Falling Skies                     4x01     Season 4, Episode 1                  Jun/2014
Bones                             9x03     El Carnicero en el Coche             Sep/30/2013
Sleepy Hollow                     1x03     For the Triumph of Evil              Sep/30/2013
Greys Anatomy                     10x03    Everybody's Crying Mercy             Oct/03/2013
Haven                             4x04     Lost and Found                       Oct/04/2013
New Girl                          3x03     Double Date                          Oct/01/2013
```

As you can see it still is not sorting correctly.

Comment: you want to sort the logs ??

Comment: sort what exactly? There's thousands of examples of all kinds of sorts already out there

Comment: Yes. It is a file that contains a tv show title, an episode number, and the release date.

Comment: I want to sort by the release date of the tv show. I know there are many guides, but none match this date format

Comment: Not sure if the person who downvoted this question is aware that this can be done via command-line; but, in any case, it can - and is rightly a linux playland question.

Comment: Try sort -k2M -k3 -k4

Comment: Not true @shellter - try opening a file and paste the text above into it. Even if that were an issue, the `-t` option would negate that issue. More info at the [manpages](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort).

Comment: Take a look at the edit, I used the + symbol as a delimter

Comment: +1 for problem description illustrated with example data **including spaces in Episode names**, sample code and output of example data illustrating the problem. ReideAndKat, good show, but you'll have to build a filter function (I'd recommend awk), to find items like 'Jan/2013' and replace with 'Jan/00/2013' (or 'Jan/33?/2013', you get the idea.) Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort` command - more information/examples can be [found at this tutorial](http://linux.101hacks.com/linux-commands/sort-command-examples/).

[And a link to the man page is here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) (`man sort`).

EDIT 2: <s>Since you updated your **data**, the solution would be: `sort -t '+' -k 4.8,4.11 -k 4.1M -k 4.5,4.6 -b my_file.txt`</s>

As @sdenham pointed out, the previous answer luckily worked on your example text. However, throwing in some older years breaks the command.

One quick way to solve this using the same command would be to substitute bad dates with a pseudo-day field.

```
cat example.txt | sed 's:\(.[[:space:]][[:alpha:]]*\)/\([[:digit:]]*\)$:\1/15/\2:g' | sort -t '+' -k 4.8,4.11 -k 4.1M -k 4.5,4.6 -b
```

Basically, I just threw in a `day` field of `15` for each row which only had a month/year. Pretty hackish, but it works. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

Provided, that is, you're actually using the data format you recently updated with. (`Bones + 9x03 + El Carnicero en el Coche + Sep/30/2013`)

Comment: I have done this, however, because of the odd date format, the sort does not come out properly

Comment: I have been trying for a few hours now. I can't seem to find the right syntax/format

Comment: Actually, you don't need `sed`. Try this: `sort -k 3 -M asdf.txt`

Comment: See my update. For future reference, never use 'fake' data, as it needlessly obfuscates the actual problem.

Comment: your solution is close, however, it lists September after October. I think it would be easier to convert the date to a sortable format

Comment: @ReidandKat One more attempt - `sort -t '+' -k 4.8,4.11 -k 4.1M -k 4.5,4.6 -b my_file.txt`

Comment: @Momer It only 'works' by chance, as it does not account for dates without the day-of-month. Change Jun/2014 to Jun/2013 in the example, and you will see what I mean. The data may have to be pre-processed before it can be sorted by a Linux or POSIX sort.

Comment: @sdenham true, I threw in a hackish solution for accuracy.